# error: nav_msgs/LoadMap.h for melodic ROS

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS in Ubuntu 18.04 Molodic for turtlebot2.

I tried to follow the steps from
https://www.programmersought.com/article/85157677089/ and I am up to the step 4: Go back to the workspace directory and compile which is simply just compile it using the following commend.
**cd ~/catkin_ws/
catkin_make**

However it suggests I to use catkin_make_isloated as there are error messages of "**This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build**"

Hence I used  **catkin_make_isloated** then I get

**/home/robot/catkin_ws/src/navigation/map_server/test/rtest.cpp:39:10:
fatal
error: nav_msgs/LoadMap.h: No such file or directory#include <nav_msgs/LoadMap.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.**

Could anyone help me with it, please? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382237/error:-nav_msgs/loadmap.h-for-melodic-ros/) by [kwan574](https://answers.ros.org/users/77571/kwan574/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I just fix the issue by redownloading files from the GitHub page. Please make sure your ROS version match the branch name. For example, I am using Melodic so I switch to the melodic-devel branch and then download it.
The GitHub page is https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/melodic-devel

---

Originally posted by [kwan574](https://answers.ros.org/users/77571/kwan574/) with karma: 16 on 2021-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0